# How to boot up 2 spring boot application in one test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

I have two spring boot applications (REST services) that should run on different ports.

I want to combine them together in one integration test. For one application, it looks like:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = FirstApplication.class)
@WebIntegrationTest({"server.port=8080", "management.port=0"})
```

They are totally different. How could they be started in one method?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to set it in your application.properties file or yaml? Something like

> server.port=${port:8080}

I think that you'll find more info here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html

Comment: Thanks, Peter, but i have 2 applications, how to map it on FirstApplication and SecondApplication?

Comment: Do your apps have one for each application.properties file? If yes just open one instance of your IDE and next instance of your IDE, set it simply like (server: port: YOUR_PORT) and run... it worked for me and started correctly on port which I chose (in my example it is port 8080 for first app and 8081 for second app)

Comment: thx for reply. it has almost the same configuration but no application.properties there, it runs by annotation configuration. how do i can point to separate properties files